# Use of undeclared type issue

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, parse-platform

In my last function on this code selection sample, Xcode is generating  an "Use of undeclared type 'allEntries' error.  I have viewed several posts on this topic and still having issues. Not sure making the variable public is the issue here since all in the same class.

```
import UIKit

class AllEntriesTableViewController: UITableViewController {

var passedValue = ""
var allEntries = [String]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


    var user = PFUser.currentUser()
    let event = PFObject(className:"event")
    var query = PFQuery(className:"event")
    query.whereKey("user", equalTo: user)
    query.includeKey("category")
    let category = event["category"] as NSString
    query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
    (objects: [AnyObject]!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
    if error == nil {
    // The find succeeded.
    self.allEntries.removeAll(keepCapacity: true)
    // Do something with the found objects
    for object in objects {
        var allEnt:String = object as String
        self.allEntries.append(allEnt)
        //self.allEntries.append(allEnt.category)
    }
    } else {
    // Log details of the failure
    NSLog("Error: %@ %@", error, error.userInfo!)
    }
    }



    // Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between presentations
    // self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = false

     //Uncomment the following line to display an Edit button in the navigation bar for this view controller.
     //self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem()
        }

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

// MARK: - Table view data source

override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView!) -> Int {
    // #warning Potentially incomplete method implementation.
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete method implementation.
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return 3
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cellsForSection: [allEntries] = sections[indexPath!.section] as Array
    return cellsForSection[indexPath!.row] as allEntries
```

Comment: `allEntries` is a *variable* and not a *type*, therefore `let cellsForSection: [allEntries] =  ...` and `... as allEntries` makes no sense at all. What did you expect it to do?

Comment: trying to return the allEntries array as the cells, I'm going about this all wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`allEntries` is a variable and not a class. Therefore a cast like in your last line

```
as allEntries
```

does not work. You must return an object from type `UITableViewCell` in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`.

Comment: Changed to - override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        
        var cell:UITableViewCell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell") as UITableViewCell
        cell.textLabel!.text = allEntries[indexPath.row]
        return cell
    } --- but now giving fatal error: Cannot index empty buffer
(lldb) debugging error at line -> cell.textLabel!.text.......row]

Comment: Any thoughts or directions to resources on using a returned array to create a table - not just cell label would be appreciated.

Comment: You have to Return a Single cell, not an array in cellForRowAtIndexPath. I would recommend to checkout the programming guides: [guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/AboutTableViewsiPhone/AboutTableViewsiPhone.html)